# Regex get matched and unmatched parts

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that would containing  and  tags. I know parsing HTML with Regex is not a good option but here since I would only be getting a handful of tags from a WYSIWYG editor, I am using this approach.

What I want to achieve is split the string into ordinary text and tags. E.g.:

```
string str = "Hi I am normal text <strong>but bold</strong> and normal again";
```

I want the output to be:

```
[Hi I am normal text,
<strong>but bold</strong>, 
and normal again]
```

So far I have tried both Regex Split and Match using a combination of various expressions like `(<[^<>]*>)`, `<([^.>]+).*\s*\1>` and `<\s*([^.>]+)[^>]*>.*?<\s*/\s*\1\s*>` but none of these seem to work

Comment: As you noted, regex is not the tool for the job. I would strongly suggest using something else like html agility pack

Comment: You could also write a state machine that parses it

Comment: What would you do if tags are nested, like `<strong><i>bla</i></strong>` ?

Comment: If I was doing this in PowerShell, I would probably try something like `<strong>.*?<\/strong>` and try to use use it on the string twice.  One time to get all matches, and the other time to split the string.  Without actually trying this, hard to say how well that would work out.  The same should be doable in C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Regex.Split` also outputs captured substrings together with split chunks.

In this scenario, you need to find matches consecutively, and append chunks to the list on the go:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var tststr = @"Hi I am normal text <strong>but bold</strong> and normal again";
        var lst = new List<string>();
        var former_idx = 0;
        for (var m = Regex.Match(tststr, @"(?s)\s*<(\w+)\b[^>]*>.*?</\1>\s*"); m.Success; m = m.NextMatch())
        {
            lst.Add(tststr.Substring(former_idx, m.Index - former_idx));
            lst.Add(m.Value);
            former_idx = m.Index + m.Value.Length;
        }
        if (former_idx < tststr.Length)
            lst.Add(tststr.Substring(former_idx, tststr.Length - former_idx));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", lst));
    }
}
```

See the [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/wWWLtN) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Od0tRg/1).

*Details*:

- `(?s)` - `RegexOptions.Singleline` option inline option making `.` match across lines
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `<` - a `<` char
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or more word chars
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `[^>]*` - zero or more chars other than `>`
- `>` - a `>` char
- `.*?` - zero or more chars as few as possible
- `</\1>` - `</` + Group 1 value + `>`.
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces.